# Java - how to get a specific parameter from a ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, list, arraylist

I've the following array list:

```
private List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
```

And If I print the object I will get the following values:

```
[{col_a = {"a":1,"b":2}, col_a = {"a":1,"b":2}, col_c = "test"},{col_a = {"a":1,"b":2}, col_a = {"a":1,"b":2}, col_c = "test1"}]
```

I'm trying to make a loop to print a specific value from my array list. Basically, I want to print the col_c in each iteration.
For that I am trying with this:

```
for (String i : data){
    System.out.println(i.col_c);
}
```

But I cannot get the col_c because i is a String.

How can I do that? My final output it will be:

```
test
test1
```

Thanks!

Comment: Your question is unclear, wdym `"print the object"` , + is `{col_a = {"a":1,"b":2}` a string? because I can't see a list of strings here: `[{col_a = {"a":1,"b":2}, col_a = {"a":1,"b":2}, col_c = "test"},{col_a = {"a":1,"b":2}, col_a = {"a":1,"b":2}, col_c = "test1"}]
`

Comment: You don't have objects with a `col_c` field.  You have strings.  You will need to parse the strings into actual objects -- probably with a JSON parser, looking at your data.

Comment: Can you tell me how you create your `[{col_a = {"a":1,"b":2}, col_a = {"a":1,"b":2}, col_c = "test"},{col_a = {"a":1,"b":2}, col_a = {"a":1,"b":2}, col_c = "test1"}]`? This is not a `List<String>`.

Comment: Are you sure you shouldn't be using a json parser?  Those "Strings" look like json to me.

Comment: You would need to parse those strings into a Map or dedicated Pojo. Then you can do map.get("col_c"). Check gson or fasterxml for parsing.

Answer (score -1):

You can try using `data.get(col_c)`and then returning it inside the for loop and see if it works.

You can also take a look at the Oracle Documentation if you need help on ArrayLists:  [ArrayList -  Java Platform SE 6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int))

Comment: The example that the question has is not correct since there is no object that will save col_c= "test" the "=" part should only be inside a string and not like the question have.

therefor, you need to comment on the question instead of putting an answer that will benifit no one.

keep up the participation.
Regards,